# Socket em C nao compila

Tags: c, socket

Estou com problemas para criar um socket em C no Linux Ubuntu. 
Ja fiz de tudo como o cara explica na aula e meu codigo nao compila.

Codigo

```
GNU nano 2.5.3                          Arquivo: socket.c                                                            

#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main()
{
        int meusocket;
        int conecta;

        struct sockaddr_in alvo;

        meusocket  = socket(AF_INET, SOCKET_STREAM, 0);
        alvo.sin_family = AF_INET;
        alvo.sin_port = htons(80);
        alvo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");

        conecta = connect(meusocket, (struct sockaddr *)&alvo, sizeof alvo);

        if(conecta == 0)
        {
                printf("Porta aberta \n");
                close(meusocket);
                close(conecta);
        }else{
                printf("Porta Fechada \n");
        }
}
```

Erro Na hora de Compilar

> ```
> socket.c: In function ‘main’:
> socket.c:11:31: error: ‘SOCKET_STREAM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   meusocket  = socket(AF_INET, SOCKET_STREAM, 0);
>                                ^
> socket.c:11:31: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
> socket.c:14:25: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘inet_addr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>   alvo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");
>                          ^
> socket.c:21:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘close’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>    close(meusocket);
> ```

Comment: Dei uma formatada na pergunta para que ela se adeque ao site e se torne mais legivel.

Comment: Ok obrigado haha, eu estava tentando fazer isso , vi que nao ficou tao legivel como eu queria.

Comment: los mensajes de error deben enviarse a `stderr`, not` stdout`.  Cuando el error proviene de una función del sistema, use `perror ()` para que la razón por la que el sistema cree que se produjo el error también se emita

Comment: respecto a: `meusocket  = socket(AF_INET, SOCKET_STREAM, 0);`  quizás quisiste decir: ``meusocket  = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`

Answer (score 2):

sugerir código:

1. incorporar os comentários à pergunta
2. compilar de forma limpa
3. documenta por que cada arquivo de cabeçalho está incluído

e agora o código proposto

```
#include <stdio.h>        // printf(), perror()
#include <sys/types.h>    // AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
#include <sys/socket.h>   // socket(), connect()
#include <netinet/in.h>   // struct sockaddr_in
#include <arpa/inet.h>    // htons(), inet_addr()
#include <unistd.h>       // close()
//#include <netdb.h>

int main( void )
{
        int meusocket;
        int conecta;

        struct sockaddr_in alvo;

        meusocket  = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        alvo.sin_family = AF_INET;
        alvo.sin_port = htons(80);
        alvo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");

        conecta = connect(meusocket, (struct sockaddr *)&alvo, sizeof alvo);

        if(conecta == 0)
        {
                printf("Porta aberta \n");
                close(meusocket);
                //close(conecta);
        }else{
                perror( "connect falhou" );
                printf("Porta Fechada \n");
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , consegui compilar com seu codigo , muito obrigado :)

Comment: como a estrutura `sockaddr_in alvo` é automática (criada na pilha), então é necessário que seja zerada antes de ser utilizada:

`struct sockaddr_in alvo; memset(&alvo, 0, sizeof(alvo));`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Valeu mesmo, aprendi muito...